# Find $\min\big\{ \lfloor xy + \frac{1}{xy} \rfloor \,\Big|\, (x+1)(y+1)=2 ,\, 0<x,y \in \mathbb{R} \big\}$

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

I am invited to calculate the minimum of the following set:

$\big\{ \lfloor xy + \frac{1}{xy} \rfloor \,\Big|\, (x+1)(y+1)=2 ,\, 0<x,y \in \mathbb{R} \big\}$.

Is there any idea?

(The question changed because there is no maximum for the set (as proved in the following answers) and I assume that the source makes mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $xy+x+y=1$ and $x>0$, $y>0$ it follows that $xy<1$. Since $t\mapsto t+{1\over t}$ is decreasing when $t<1$ we conclude that we have to make
 $xy$ is as large as possible. Let $x+y=:s$. Then
$$1-s=xy\leq{s^2\over4}\ .$$ 
The largest possible $xy$ goes with the smallest admissible $s>0$, and the latter satisfies $1-s={\displaystyle{s^2\over4}}$. This leads then to $$x=y={s\over2}=\sqrt{2}-1\ ,$$ and finally to
$$xy+{1\over xy}=6\ ,$$
which is already an integer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a minimum of $6$ achieved at $x=y=\sqrt{2}-1$

to prove this, start with the identity

$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)+\left(\frac{y}{x}+\frac{x}{y}\right)=\left(x y+\frac{1}{x y}\right)$

a simple verification shows that $\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)=4$

on the other hand $\frac{y}{x}+\frac{x}{y}\geq 2$

it follows that $x y+\frac{1}{x y}\geq 6$

Comment: Could you corroborate your "simple verification"?

Comment: @ Christian Blatter $(x+1)(y+1)=xy+y+x+1=2$

Comment: i am sorry but i am not able to continue with my previous comment (5 minute warning or something like that) so please solve for y and replace and a few algebra steps later you get that the expression = 4

Comment: (ok work offline to prepare the comment and then sign in and copy and paste)

$y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}-\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\frac{x^2-1}{x}\left(\frac{-4x}{1-x^2}\right)=4$

Answer (score 1):

This needs further verification.

*I believe that the maximum does not exist since the set is not bounded above.*

Suppose $x, y \gt 0$ satisfies $ (x + 1)(y + 1) = 2 $. Then we can conclude that

1. $ xy + x+ y = 1 $
2. $ 1 + \dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{1}{xy}  $ (dividing by $xy$)

Subtracting equation $2$ from $1$ we can rearrange this to $$ xy + \dfrac{1}{xy} = 2 + \left({\dfrac{1}{x} - x}\right  ) +  \left({\dfrac{1}{y} - y}\right  ) $$

Now notice that the expression $\left({\dfrac{1}{t} - t}\right  )$ can be made arbitrarily large by making $t$ arbitrarily small. Hence the floor function  $ \lfloor xy + \frac{1}{xy} \rfloor  $ is also not bounded above and so the maximum of the given set cannot exist.

Comment: @user221158: Does not matter. We can take both $x$ and $y$ to be very small and make the expression on the right very large. Hence the one on the left will also be very large.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Solve for one variable using the equation $(x+1)(y+1)=2$.  Solving for $x$ we get $x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$.  Then rewrite the floor function as $\lfloor{xy+\frac{1}{xy}}\rfloor=\lfloor{\frac{y^2(1-y)^2+(1+y)^2}{y(1-y^2)}}\rfloor$, so there is no max, taking $y \rightarrow 1$

Comment: @user221158 When $y \to 1$, $x \to 0 $

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.